# Problema al inicializar un array en AndroidStudio

Tags: android-studio

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que cada vez que pulsas un botón, cambie el texto que se muestra por un string aleatorio. Los strings están almacenados en un arraylist. El código que tenía hasta ahora era el siguiente:

```
private TextView texto;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_basic_game);


    texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
}

public void cambiarMensaje(View v){

    int aleatorio;
    int total;

    ArrayList<String> preguntas = new ArrayList<>();


    preguntas.add("String 1");
    preguntas.add("String 2");
    ...

    int longitud = preguntas.size();
    while(longitud > 0){
        aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * longitud);
        String s = preguntas.get(aleatorio);
        texto.setText(String.format(s));
        preguntas.remove(aleatorio);
        longitud--;
    }
}
```

El problema es que cada vez que pulsaba el botón, se inicializaba el arraylist con todas las frases de nuevo. Traté de solucionarlo con los siguientes cambios:

```
private TextView texto;
ArrayList<String> preguntas = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_basic_game);

    preguntas.add("String 1");
    preguntas.add("String 2");
    ...

    texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
}

public void cambiarMensaje(View v){

    int aleatorio;
    int total;





    int longitud = preguntas.size();
    while(longitud > 0){
        aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * longitud);
        String s = preguntas.get(aleatorio);
        texto.setText(String.format(s));
        preguntas.remove(aleatorio);
        longitud--;
    }
}
```

El problema ahora es que cuando pulso el botón se muestra una sola frase (el botón funciona solo una vez). Entonces mi pregunta es que no entiendo muy bien donde se supone que tengo que añadir las frases al arraylist y donde tengo que declararlo, o si hay alguna forma de arreglar el segundo código.

Comment: Me parece que lo que deseas es un mensaje aleatorio de los contenidos en el ArrayList

Comment: Disculpa, podrias decirme como solucionaste tu problema intento hacer algo semejante al tu yo. final String[] ex = { "rapido", "lento", "limpio", "ordenado", "sucio", "desordenado", "enojado", "feliz", "triste", "bueno", "malo", "bonito", "feo", "hermosa", "guapo", }; //Generar btn_Generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { Random rand = new Random(); int Questions = rand.nextInt(15); edt_Questions.setText(ex[Questions]); } });

Answer (score 0):

En realidad no es problema de inicialización, lo que sucede es que estas eliminando los elementos hasta dejar solo uno en el `ArrayList`.

De acuerdo a tu bucle, mientras la longitud del `ArrayList` es mayor a 0 va a obtener un elemento aleatoriamente de tu `ArrayList` pero va eliminando ese elemento ( `preguntas.remove(aleatorio)` ), por lo tanto al final obtendría solo un elemento, pero elimino todos los demás en el `ArrayList`.

Si deseas conservar los elementos en el `ArrayList` evita usar `remove()`:

```
 while(longitud > 0){
        aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * longitud);
        String s = preguntas.get(aleatorio);
        texto.setText(String.format(s));
       // preguntas.remove(aleatorio);
        longitud--;
    }
```

De esta forma permanecerán los elementos que agregaste inicialmente en el `ArrayList`.

---

Veo que agregas el mensaje a un `TextView` o `EditText`

```
    texto.setText(String.format(s));
```

si deseas obtener un mensaje aleatorio de los almacenados en el `ArrayList` puedes obtenerlo de esta forma evitando usar un bucle:

```
 private Random randomGenerator;

   public void cambiarMensaje(View v){

        randomGenerator = new Random();
        int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(preguntas.size());
        String s = preguntas.get(index);
        texto.setText(String.format(s));

   }
```

Comment: Supongo que no quiere que los elementos se repitan y a su vez mostrar todos, por eso necesita el remove().

Comment: Solo necesita un "mensaje" ya que en realidad lo esta asignando a un TextView:  texto.setText(String.format(s));

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. Efectivamente, el bucle while era un error debido a una copia mal hecha, debería haber usado un bucle if, de esa forma cuando se acaben los mensajes a mostrar se acabaría el juego. El remove, sin embargo, es necesario para que el juego termine e ir eliminando las frases que sean mostradas.

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaría un array auxiliar que se llenaría al momento de presionar el botón, con los mismos valores del array pregunta. Y luego, dentro del while trabajaras con tu nuevo array, de manera que "preguntas" no se modifique nunca. Algo así:

```
public void cambiarMensaje(View v){
    ArrayList<String> auxiliar = new ArrayList<>();
    int aleatorio;
    int total;

    for (int i = 0; i < preguntas.size(); i++) {
        String valor = preguntas[i];
        auxiliar.add(valor);
    }
    int longitud = preguntas.size();

    while(longitud > 0){
        aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * longitud);
        String s = auxiliar.get(aleatorio);
        texto.setText(String.format(s));
        auxiliar.remove(aleatorio);
        longitud--;
    }
}
```

Para el resto del código mantendrás la segunda opción que subiste.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, sin embargo, mi objetivo es que el array se quede vacío una vez que se hayan mostrado todas las frases, así que necesito utilizar el array original.

Comment: Pero estás en una contradicción entonces. Necesitas vaciar el array pero a su vez conservarlo para la siguiente iteracion.

Answer (score 0):

creo que el while no es necesario .

intenta con esto

```
public void cambiarMensaje(View v){

    int aleatorio;


    int longitud = preguntas.size();
    if(longitud > 0){
        aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * longitud);
        String s = preguntas.get(aleatorio);
        texto.setText(String.format(s));
        preguntas.remove(aleatorio);

    }
   else
   {
      texto.setText("Se terminaron las frases");
   }
}
```